# How to access PHP files and SQL DB from localhost to other computers on the same network?

Tags: php, mysql

I have completed a project that includes some PHP files and a MySQL database on the localhost computer.  Now, five computers that are on the same network need to be able to access those PHP files and the database.  I tried using the IP address of the localhost computer on the client computers but no luck.  All computers runs Windows 10, with Windows Defender ON.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the computer have a firewall turned on?

Comment: are you using Wamp Server? if so you need to set it to be online and then another computer will be able to access the ip address of the localhost (which can be found using ipconfig)